# Arc is changing decimals!! My scale is set to 2, why do my numbers in the select by attributes-unique values have more decimals?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes

My scale is set to 2.  Yet arc (using 10.2) is showing (in my select by attribute - get unique values) my number of 26.67  as 26.670000000000002.   My value of 25.25 is shown correctly as 25.25 in the same field.

Again my value of 32.60 is shown as 32.6000000000001.

I have tried replacing the values with the field calculator, but it goes back to these long decimal numbers all on its own.

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

These values are not more than 2 decimals, showing more is wrong. but it has to be a double because there are some negatives ..

Comment: Generating unique values on IEEE floating point values will frequently cause this sort of issue -- Would you prefer a value which will match an equivalence test or one that that uses your preferred formatting?  You can't have both.

Comment: I don't completely understand your answer. Preferred formatting is what I want! That's why I set the scale to 2. Anything beyond that is wrong.

Comment: What's your field type?

Comment: it's a double, mentioned it, (not so clearly at the end)

Comment: Some user interface controls may not respect the precision setting when rendering as a string. Remember that in hardware, it's not stored as rounded to anything at all. You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: shouldn't the software, ArcGIS, have something in it to correct this? because it should only display it as the scale and precision set..

Comment: Your query is for the unique values.  If it returned the values formatted, you could not ever obtain result rows based on the altered values, which is the assumed purpose of the unique value request.  The *why* is outside the scope of GSE (how floating point-representation works), and the net result of the "how to fix it" is probably "you can't" (unless you're willing to change to an integral datatype, with units of hundredths of your original units).  I don't understand your "negative values" reasoning for using floating-point representation.

Comment: I should have said it's a double because a few numbers are negative with a field length more than 7 and a scale of 2. By definition, it can't be a short or a long.  A different field that is a float, with a field length of 5 and a scale of 3 is doing the same thing.

Comment: What format is the data stored in? File geodatabase, shape, etc.

Comment: It is a shapefile.

Comment: By definition, you *can* use a 32-bit integer to store floating-point length field with two places to the right of the decimal, if you change the units from meters to centimeters and multiply all values by 100.  Doing so would reduce the storage requirements (in some formats) and generate the discrete values you require.

Answer (score 2):

This is more an overall question of how computers deal with and represent numbers and is an important question to grasp for computer programming/GIS in general. Considering the vast amount of papers on this topic I think it is best to give you a few links and they will lead into more research if you are interested on the topic.

One of the classics on the topic is ['What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic'](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or just go to any number of [questions on stack overflow that deal with this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) (look on the right side for links to other similar questions on the topic). [One more interesting link](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-questions-are-endless-on-stackoverflow-com/) that documents how often this question is asked and provides many helpful links (at the bottom of the page) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your field type is [float](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000008w000000). If you've already set your scale and the numbers are showing up with more decimal points than you specified try this:
Right click on the field in question via the attribute table --> properties select numeric
From there change the number of decimal places or significant digits.
Alternatively, set up a new field and also set your precision to the number of digits you want stored in the field.

Here is a resource outlining the difference between [precision and scale](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000)

Comment: no it's a double, have some negatives..  I already set the correct scale and precision.  the numeric is set correctly as well.  I am not sure you understand or I did not explain myself clearly in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

See this link for this answer:

[Add Field Discussion at ESRI](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/add_field_data_management_.htm)

> When you create float and double fields and specify a precision and scale, if your precision is greater than 6, use a double; otherwise, use a float. **If you create a double field and specify a precision of 6 or less, a float field is created.** If you create a float field and specify a precision greater than 6, a double field is created.